# Should "http://" be stored with a database record of a URL?

Tags: database, url, user-input

There are a number of fields a user can fill in where they'd enter a URL (their personal website, business site, favorite sites, etc etc).

It's the only thing they'd be entering in that particular field.

So should I always strip out "http://" to keep it consistent and to also reduce the possibility of broken links (ie. "http//")?

Just not sure what the best way to store URLs is.

Comment: Is there a reason to remove it at all? what about distinguishing between that and HTTPS? I would say a URL with a protocol is more useful than one without.

Comment: For consistency. So Joe Schmoe may enter "http://" while Bob Smith may not enter it. I need it to be consistent when I output the link.

Comment: in cases of https, if a uses types http then the server automatically redirects to https. so even if the http is added no harm is done

Comment: Personally (and I think this is subjective) if someone submitted a URL without a protocol I would assume HTTP, add it to the input and store that.

Comment: @Shpigford - If output consistency is the concern, then you can handle  stripping the protocol or cleaning it up, if needed, in the UI. That way, the data remains intact, and if you find that you need to change the behavior, you have not lost any data.

Comment: @nonouco: You shouldn't make that assumption, it's not always going to be true.

Comment: @Alex: Yes thats true, some servers work both with http and https. so the worst case scenario for users that ignore protocol is that they add an https site, which is saved as http and the next time they access it, its through http. In any case, https awareness is a big deal and I think not the topic of the post.

Comment: @nonouco: No -- the worst case scenario is that the outbound link flat out doesn't work. You're erroneously assuming that `https://site.com` always implies the existence of `http://site.com`, and with the same content. However, neither of these implications are a given. If I type in https and the OP's site strips it off and replaces it with http, then clicking the link can result in the wrong site or a server not found error. Endeavoring to prevent that from happening is exactly on topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there's a reason to sanitize your users' input (security, size, speed, accuracy...) then do it.

But otherwise, don't.

There's actually a benefit a lot of times in taking your customer-input data as-is.  They own their own typos or misspellings, broken links, etc. that way.  As long as it doesn't cause a problem for you (i.e. you don't have a reason to sanitize it).

BTW -- consistency is a moot point, as it won't change the data type, and you can easily check for the "http://" and add or remove it as necessary in your presentation layers with a re-usable function.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know you actually can not call it an "URL", without having the protocol part:

http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt

I wouldn't remove it.

However if you really need to keep the data consistent, it really depends how the URL is actually typed in your application. If it's a browser-like application, I'd bet it can be assumed to be http:// in front if there is none, for valid links.